# Breeze.js OData predicates for local execution of Query

Tags: javascript, breeze

I am building dynamic filter string using checkbox like example below

`(IsIssue eq false) and (ProjectId eq 1)`

The query is totally dynamic and can be combination of anything.

`(IsIssue eq false or IsIssue eq true) and (OwnerDetailsId eq 16 or OwnerDetailsId eq 9) and (ProjectId eq 1)`

Now, I want to use it as filter in query. I want to query data from local cache using `executeQueryLocally` just by passing the above string in filter `.where(querystring)`. It works well for `executeQuery` but returns below exception when I try it on `executeQueryLocally..`

`OData predicateexpressions cannot be interpreted locally`

How can I tackle this situation? Is there any custom Predicate builder?